# Max-norm and trace-norm matrix completion — which one is better?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm, spectral-norm, matrix-completion

Let $X$ be a matrix. The max-norm regularizes maximum of its singular values

$$|X|_{\infty} = \max(\sigma_i)$$

while trace-norm penalizes sum of all singular values

$$|X|_* = \sum_{i = 1}^m \sigma_i$$

However, the trace-norm is now much more popular in matrix completion, mainly because

- nice theoretical analysis, e.g., [Candès 2009](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10208-009-9045-5), and
- fast algorithms to do optimization, like proximal gradient descents ones ([active](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/hsiehb14.pdf), [AIS-Impute](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~qyaoaa/papers/ijcai2015paper.pdf)).

**However, besides computational issues, in practice, which one performs better?**

I've seen some old comments on this topic:

- Practical Large-Scale Optimization for Max-Norm Regularization. NIPS 2010.

which said max-norm gave better prediction on non-uniform sampled data. If this were true, then max-norm should be better in real cases due to long-tail effects.

Comment: They do different things. What is "better" depends on the application. For instance, minimizing the nuclear norm tends to favor low-rank solutions, whereas the spectral norm does not. So it really doesn't make sense to ask which is "better" without specifying the *specific* application you're considering.

Comment: Yeah, for recommendation, like commonly used movielens and Netflix, how about that?